# how to record data on excel from a form in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, activexobject

I don't have access to our servers so I need to find a different way to make this work. Javascript appears to be the only way since I have not yet learned jQuery yet.

I slapped together this code below, but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm missing. It fires up fine and no errors pop up, but when I look up the file its supposed to be storing in, there is nothing there. Any insight anyone may have would be greatly appreciated.

Please ignore the useless code to my issue, just wanted to show the whole idea behind it. I know its really rough around the edges... okay, its pretty messed up, but its what I am working with at the moment. Promise it will get better with time as I learn more updated codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #right {
    text-align:right;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function write_to_excel()   {

  str="";

  var mytable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  var row_Count = mytable.rows.length;
  var col_Count = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td").length;    

  var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
  var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("pathwaytoexcel.xlsx");
  var ExcelSheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
  ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = false;

  for(var i=0; i < row_count ; i++) {   
    for(var j=0; j < col_Count; j++) {           
      str = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j].innerHTML;
      ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = str;
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">

<h2>Call tracking</h2>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5">

<tr>
    <td><div id="right">Positive Response?</div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes1" >Yes 
        <input type="checkbox" id="No1"  >No</td>
</tr>                           
<tr>                            
    <td><div id="right">Negative Response?</div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes2" >Yes
        <input type="checkbox" id="No2"  >No</td>
</tr>                           
<tr>                            
    <td><div id="right">Paid with Representative</div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes3" >Yes
        <input type="checkbox" id="No3"  >No</td>
</tr>                           
<tr>                            
    <td><div id="right">Previously made Payment<br /> <i>(Add ID number if yes)</i></div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes4" onclick="promptForID()" >Yes
                <input type="checkbox" id="No4"  >No</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="text4" value="Enter ID" style="display:none"></td>
</tr>                           
<tr>                            
    <td><div id="right">Would like to wait to make Payment?</div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes5" >Yes
        <input type="checkbox" id="No5"  >No</td>
</tr>                           
<tr>                            
    <td><div id="right">Can't Pay No card or check</div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes6" >Yes
        <input type="checkbox" id="NA6"  >N/A</td>
</tr>                           
<tr>                            
    <td><div id="right">Requesting Cancellation?</div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes7" onclick="promptForComment()">Yes
        <input type="checkbox" id="No7"  >No</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="text7" value="Enter comments" style="display:none"></td>
</tr>
<tr>                            
    <td><div id="right">Requested a callback?</div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Yes8" onclick="promptForTel()">Yes 
        <input type="checkbox" id="No8"  >No </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="text8" value="Contact Number" style="display:none"></td>
</tr>                           

</div>  
</table>

<input type="button" value="Restart" onclick="reloadPage()">
<input type="submit" value="Export to EXCEL" onclick="write_to_excel();"/>

<script>
function promptForID () {
  var checkedYes = document.getElementById("Yes4").checked;
  if (checkedYes == true) {
    document.getElementById("text4").style.display = "block";
  } else {                              
    document.getElementById("text4").style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<script>
function promptForComment () {
  var checkedYes = document.getElementById("Yes7").checked;

  if (checkedYes == true) {
    document.getElementById("text7").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text7").style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<script>
function promptForTel() {
    var checkedYes = document.getElementById("Yes8").checked;

if(checkedYes == true){
    document.getElementById("text8").style.display = "block";
}
else    {
    document.getElementById("text8").style.display = "none";
}

}
</script>

<script> 
  function reloadPage () {
    location.reload();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you plan on supporting more than just IE? Additionally, not knowing jQuery has nothing to do with your problem. It's just a library.

Comment: No, we only use IE. It just seems like using jQuery is easier. So I've noticed, I've not looked at any of its methods of use or how its used, yet. I plan to mildly soon.

Comment: I weep for your users. In any case, if you can't access anything on the server, then yes, this is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the advise on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry,**
It isn't possible with just HTML / JS / JQuery, etc.
These languages are on the client side, so if you wanted to read / write to a file, you would need a serverside language ex: PHP. There is a thing called NodeJS, but it is really just JavaScript ported as a server-side language.

TL;DR
**Nope, PHP / another server-side language is the only way**